# Transformation of an exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Suppose that $X\sim Exp(p)$ is exponentially distributed with expectation $1/p$. Does there exist transformation $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(X)$ will be some (ideally "nice") distribution with expectation $\mathbb{E}f(X)=p$? Here, $f$ can not depend on $p$.

Context: In GLM models (generalized linear models) we usually deal with a random variables $Y\sim exp(p)$  where $p=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1$. So $\mathbb{E}Y=\frac{1}{\beta_0+\beta_1X_1}$ which is kind of ugly. It would be nice if we can change Y in such a way that $f(Y)$ will have nice linear expectation. Is it possible?

Comment: Most likely no. I wouldn't know how to argue formally, but if $f$ is smooth around then $f(x) = f(1/p) + f'(1/p)(x-1/p) + f''(1/p)/2(x - 1/p)^2 + \ldots$ by Taylor expansion centred at $1/p.$ Then, $E(X) = f(1/p) +f''(1/p) \sigma_X^2/2 + \ldots$. You want the LHS to be $p$ and the RHS definitely depends on $p...$

Comment: $$
\text{For every } p>1,\quad \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-px}(p\,dx) = p.
$$
The problem is whether a function $f$ exists for which this is true. $\qquad$

Comment: $$
\text{For every } p>1,\quad \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-px}(p\,dx) = p.
$$
$$
p = \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-px}(p\,dx) = p(\mathcal Lf)(p),
$$
where $\mathcal Lf$ is the Laplace transform of $f.$ So
$$
(\mathcal Lf)(p) = 1 \text{ for all } p>0.
$$

Comment: One thing we *can* do, inspired by Michael Hardy's comments, is to let $f_n = n\cdot[0,\frac1n]$ (or anything with similar properties), where $[\cdot]$ is an indicator function. Then $\mathbb E f_n(X) \to p$ for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Why was this question closed? I feel like this is very legitimate question

Comment: @AlbertParadek While the question itself was legitimate, the way you wrote it (before the edit) was quite short, and showed no context, motivation, or effort on your part. In fact it looked like you might just have given us your homework. Such questions almost always get closed (they call them PSQs, Problem Statement Questions, on the meta site). However, your edit helps a lot, and I will vote to reopen.

Comment: @AlbertParadek Basically, the first bullet point [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/620957)

Comment: All that said, I should point out in the meantime now, that Michael Hardy's derivation shows that the Dirac delta, $\delta$, would be the only possible choice of $f$ (look up inverse Laplace transform), and that is no good! $\delta$ is not a function, so $\delta(X)$ is meaningless. I think the closest you can get are approximations like the ones in my comment, but I would hardly think that's very useful...

Comment: Really? I always hated when people write a long text that has nothing to do with the problem itself. I always try to shorten it as much as possible. 

Anyway yeah, I am also starting to belive that its not possible. Too bad, but thanks for your time

Comment: I certainly see your point. The problem is that the site easily gets swamped with short and low effort questions, many of which are likely just homework, so the guidelines are there to manage that. I do think your editted version is much better, and not too long at all; it allows the reader to get in your mindset and maybe even give alternative suggestions to the underlying problem. And it sort of makes it seem like you care, which goes a long way in my book :)

Comment: @AlbertParadek As a final note, you could use smooth approximations of $\delta$, e.g. $f_\alpha = \frac{2}{\alpha\sqrt\pi}e^{-(x/\alpha)^2}$ for $\alpha > 0$ very small. This at least preserves the data, since it's invertible, in contrast with my first comment. But again, it'll probably do all sorts of bad other things...

Comment: @MichaelHardy Just to let you know, the question has reopened, so you might want to convert your comments into an answer :)