# Can you use a random variable as intput to the Dirac delta, i.e. $\delta(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, dirac-delta

**Question**:

> If $X$ is a random vairable and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta, is $\delta(X)$ meaningful? Useful?

**Motivation:**

In [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4338556/620957), we have $X\sim Exp(p)$, and it is asked whether there exists a function $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, independent of $p$, such that $\Bbb Eg(X) = p$. The comments revealed that this is not possible.

However, it is possible to approximate such an $g$ by approximating a "one-sided" Dirac delta. For example, with $g_\alpha = \alpha I_{[0,\frac1\alpha]}$ for $\alpha>0$, where $I_{A}$ is an indicator function, we have in fact
$$
\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\Bbb Eg_\alpha(X) 
= \lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\Bbb E\left[\alpha I_{[0,\frac1\alpha]}(X)\right] 
= p.
$$
Knowing this, I am now tempted to simply say that $g=\delta$ somehow answers the problem (since $g_\alpha$ has the properties of $\delta$ in the limit). In other words, $\delta(X)$ should be some sort of "random variable distribution(?)" with an expected value of $p$.

*Caveat: The limit is not really $\delta$, because I don't think $\int_0^\infty\delta(x)f(x)\ dx$ is well-defined in general; or maybe it is $\frac{f(0)}{2}$? I would like something like $\delta^+$ that satisfies $\int_0^\infty\delta^+(x)f(x)\ dx = f(0)$, but I'm out of my depth here. Anyway, that's not the point of my question, so please just imagine I had chosen a better example...*

I somehow suspect $\delta(X)$ makes sense if you "intend to" use it in an integral, but naturally $\delta(X)$ will not be a random variable in the usual sense (right?). For example, I might argue that $\Bbb E \delta(X)$ is meaningful, because we can write
$$
\Bbb E \delta(X) \overset?= \int_\Bbb R \delta(x)f_X(x)\ dx = f_X(0).
$$

---

I should mention that my knowledge of the Dirac delta is rudimentary. I know how it can be used in integrals, and that it can be seen as a measure or as a distribution. I understand the measure perspective, but to be honest, I don't know the formalities of distribution theory. I think this question naturally points to a distribution perspective, because of the family of functions, and this is why I am on shaky ground here.

Comment: Isn't the delta of Dirac simply the distribution (on the space of test functions) that evaluates at zero? At any rate, you seem to want to use the measure $\varepsilon_0$ which is essentially the same, _it is defined_ by $\int f d\varepsilon_0 = f(0).$ However, I fail to see how you connect this $f = \delta$. You could have a random variable with _distribution_ exactly this measures $\varepsilon_0$ but that is uninteresting as $\varepsilon_0$ assigns total mass $1$ to the point $0$ so such a r.v. will be a.s. constant (and equal to zero).

Comment: Because $X$ is continuous, $\delta(X)$ is a random variable that is almost surely equal to $0$. As a random variable that's almost surely a constant is not very interesting in any case. What I think that he meant by $f_\alpha$ is that we can somehow approximate $p$ as close as we want using smaller and smaller $\alpha$, but never exactly.

Comment: @WillM., AlbertParadek I wouldn't think $\delta(X)$ a priori means anything, since $\delta$ isn't a function. But in the same way as $\delta$ can be seen as the limit of $g_\alpha$ for $\alpha \to \infty$ (I'm not sure if $g_\alpha$ needs to be smooth for this to be strictly true, but bear with me), then can we define $\delta(X)$ as some sort of limit of the random variables $X_\alpha:=g_\alpha(X)$, for $\alpha\to \infty$?  $\delta(X)$ should not be a random variable itself, much like $\delta$ isn't a function.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that I overused $f$ in question, so I renamed it so $g$ now refers to the problem in the link, and $f$ is a generic function or a pdf.

Comment: The expression $E[\delta(X-c)]$ is informal, but if $X\sim F_X$ with nice density $f_X$ then $E[\delta(X-c)]=f_X(c)$ is an interesting object that can provide useful intuitions for more rigorous arguments. Seen it many times in applied maths

Answer (score 2):

Standard random variables have their sample space be numbers, but random variables are much more general than that.  You can have random functions, random sets, and in this case, random functionals.  A functional is given as an inner product with a function, and outputs a number.  In this case, the random functional can have an inner product with a function, and the output is a random number.

The problem here is that $\delta(X)$ is not a function of x, which a delta function usually is.  So you would have here
$$\langle \delta(X), f(x) \rangle=\int_\mathbb{R} \delta(X) f(x) dx = ???$$ if $X=0$.  It would be $= 0$ otherwise.

What is a far more interesting object is $\delta(x-X)$.  The math here would yield
$$\langle \delta(x-X), f(x) \rangle=\int_\mathbb{R} \delta(x-X) f(x) dx = f(X)$$
so evaluating $f$ at a random value.  There is a rich amount of math that can be done with this object.

Comment: That's interesting, and makes sense. Do you then think that there is no hope of making sense e.g. of my "calculation" saying that $\Bbb E[\delta(X)] = f_X(0)$ (where $f_X$ is the PDF).

Comment: This is equivalent to the random measure $\varepsilon_X,$ which avoids the unnecesary difficulties associated with the delta of Dirac function.